# How to Set state of a component from within another component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a child react component and I would like to set the state of the parent component from the child component. How do i achieve it ?

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
     super(props);
     this.state ={
         request:{
            ip: "",
            location:""
          }
     };
  }
  render(){
    return(
          <Child request={this.state.request} />
      );
   }
}
```

Now in the child page I want to set the value of ip.

```
class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
     super(props);
     this.onChange = this.onChange.bind( this );
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <Input id = "ip" type = "text" name = "case"  onChange = { ( e ) => { this.onChange( e ); } }/>
      );
   }

onChange( e ) {
    this.setState( { ...this.props.request, ip: e } );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the most correct (and most react-ic way), but I would define a function to change the parent's state inside the parents class and pass it as prop to a child like so:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
     super(props);
     this.state ={
         request:{
            ip: ""
          }
     };
  }

  changeIP = (newIp) => {
    // Do your checks beforehand
    this.setState({
     request: {
        ...this.state.request,
        ip: newIp
     }      
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
          <Child request={this.state.request} changeIP={this.changeIP} />
      );
   }
}
```

And then inside your child class, when you want to set the parent's state, you call that function like so:

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor( props ){
       super(props);
       this.onChange = this.onChange.bind( this );
    }
    render(){
      return(
          <Input id = "ip" type = "text" name = "case"  onChange = { ( e ) => { this.onChange( e ); } }/>
        );
     }

  onChange( e ) {
      this.props.changeIP(e.target.value) // I think it should be 'e.target.value', make sure you pass the right value here
    }

  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Irek. But what if i have many parameters and not only IP in state.request

Comment: Thanks @Irek for your help, I have updated the problem a little bit, can you edit the solution. Thanks in adv

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I realised I was writing some gibberish. The solution is correct thanks to edit proposed by JS Engine. Since request is an object we have to copy the remaining values using spread operator ...this.state.request, otherwise you would overwrite the whole object. Sorry for the confusion, I removed the incorrect comment

Answer (score 1):

The parent

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
     super(props);
     this.state ={
         request:{
            ip: "",
            location:""
         }
     };
  }

  handleIpChange (value) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, request:{...this.state.request, ip : value)};
  }

  render(){
    return(
          <Child request={this.state.request} onIpChange={this.handleIpChange}/>
      );
   }
}
```

The child

```
class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
     super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <Input id = "ip" type = "text" name = "case"  onChange = {e => this.onChange(e);}/>
      );
   }

  onChange = e => this.props.onIpChange(e.target.value)

}
```

Do change the state of a higher component, you have to pass by props a function that update his state.
Do not forget, if you are not using arrow function `() => {}` you have to bind it in the higher component like that :

```
this.function = this.function.bind(this);
```

In case of multiple value to update in your state, you could also try something like that (working around name param gave to the inputs)

```
handleInputChange(e) {
        let request = Object.assign({}, this.state.request);
        switch (e.target.name) {
            case 'location': // do something specific + break; 
            case 'ip': // or let it empty if you have nothing specific to do at the moment
            default:
                request[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        }
        this.setState({request});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @craftyMonkey. But what if i have many parameters and not only IP in state.request.

Comment: You can update only a few part of the state using destructuring, something like :
`this.setState({...this.state, request: {...this.state.request, ip: value}})`

Comment: You can also have a look on the new react feature : Hooks 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the problem code little bit, can you please help. Thanks in adv. @CraftyMonkey

Comment: I dont think this will work. See there will be onChange for location also. So how will the parent know which field of the state to be updated ? @CraftyMonkey

Comment: But your parent is having only handleIpChange (value) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, request:{...this.state.request, ip : value)};
  }. So parent is always updating the IP. How will parent update the location.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a state in your children, so you cannot use the this.setState you want there.

You could send a function to Child like this :

```js
<Child 
 request={this.state.request} 
 changeRequest={(v) => {this.setState({
  request: {ip: v}
  })}}
/>
```

And then just call changeRequest in your children.